# Slash added automaticaly before bucket name with fstab and gcsfuse

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

I use gcsfuse to mount bucket in Google Compute Engine.

For this I use this syntax in my `fstab`:

```
my_bucket /my_bucket gcsfuse rw,uid=1001,gid=1002
```

But gcsfuse process is launched like this:

```
/usr/bin/gcsfuse --foreground -o rw --uid 1001 --gid 1002 /my_bucket /my_bucket
```

With "/" before "my_bucket", the mount do not work.

It runs on Ubuntu 16

Why does fstab add this `/` automatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. Must not have a bucket name like folder name in root path.

For this, i have rename my folder.

```
my_new_bucket_folder_name /my_bucket gcsfuse rw,uid=1001,gid=1002
```

Comment: Can you word this differently and go into a bit more detail? Other users looking for this issue might have a hard time understanding what the solution was.

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues/299

Comment: Thanks for a helpful answer. Just to add that in my case the directory that had the same name as the bucket was in the home directory, rather than `/`.